# Add Header to WCF Message

Tags: xml, wcf, c#-4.0, xml-serialization, xmldocument

How Can I add Header to this Message and take all xml document?

```
  private Message GetRootMessage()
  {
      var stream = new MemoryStream();
      XmlDictionaryWriter writer =  XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(stream);
      writer.WriteStartDocument();
      writer.WriteStartElement("Body");
      writer.WriteAttributeString("abc", "2012-04-17t10:00:00Z");
      writer.WriteAttributeString("abd", "CA");
      writer.WriteAttributeString("bid", "35353");

      writer.WriteEndElement();   
      writer.WriteEndDocument();
      writer.Flush();
      stream.Position = 0;

      XmlDictionaryReader reader = 
          XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(
          stream, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
      return Message.CreateMessage(
          MessageVersion.None, "", reader);
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0):

[IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is you friend here, have a look at [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6f14b940-28e2-464a-800d-99f190a22867/wcf-message-inspectors-and-response-headers) for ideas.